# List Map Services and Publish/Delete Map Services using Python in ArcGIS 10.1

Tags: python, arcgis-10.1, map-service

I looked at the link
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s30000004s000000

which describes listing of map service for 9.3, how can we do this in 10.1, moreover I am trying to start stop, publish services , I read on ArcGIS help that the new ArcGIS API Administration uses the RESTful Architecture wherein an http request is made to start/stop a service. Is there any other way? Can we delete or publish/republish a service? Any help on this is most welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Theres a whole bunch of code and tools to administer ArcGIS Server 10.1+, look here
http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=12dde73e0e784e47818162b4d41ee340
They connect to the REST end point of the Server/Services.

For the publishing of map services through Python (and arcpy), look here:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s30000006q000000